# Rollback an edit that skirts a SO rule?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code-formatting, jsfiddle

There's a built-in check when posting a question that contains a link to jsFiddle.net that the question must also contain code. Sometimes users attempt to skirt the rule by highlighting non-code text in the question as code, so that they can get around this.

I came upon a question where someone with < 2k rep had suggested an edit that added a working jsFiddle.net link to the question, with no other changes. Eventually this edit was approved.

My question is, should the suggested edit be rolled back so that there is no live link to jsFiddle.net, should it be left as-is, or should someone go to the trouble of making further edits and adding the code to the question?

I feel the last option, while the most helpful, doesn't teach the person asking the question, nor the person who suggested the edit, that they're ignoring/skirting the posting rules. I would imagine that comments to both the poster and reviewer should be made reminding them of this rule, but I'm mostly curious as to how the edit itself should be handled.

Answer (score 20):

Only edit - or roll back - if doing so makes the post better than it would've been if you hadn't.

As annoying as fiddle-only questions are, fiddle-only questions without links to the fiddle aren't really any better.

Things you could do instead:

- Edit the relevant code into the question (as is the entire purpose of this restriction)
- Vote to close as off-topic:

  > This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Which of these you opt to do is up to you: if you think the question or its answer(s) are worth saving, then do the former; if not, then do the latter.

Answer (score 6):

A comment would give the poster, editor and reviewer the alert that they should need.

Not going for the best option with the edit to 'teach them a lesson' sounds fundamentally wrong, as the post is there for the community and will thus negatively affect everyone who reads it in the future.

Thus, if you feel that an edit that includes the code would be the best edit, this is the edit that should be made.

That being said, it may have some merit to suggest this in the comments and give the people some time to 'correct their mistake', probably maximizing the learning experience.