# Rolling Back Approved Edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rollbacks

Would it be incorrect to rollback an approved suggested edit that obviously shouldn't be approved?

Sometimes an edit gets approved because the reviewers don't take time to consider it well enough and sometimes it appears to just be a flat out wrong review.  For example, this suggested edit was approved, but it clearly should have been a comment or another answer entirely:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4711938

Thus, it seems as though a rollback should be made since it was not the original intent of the author.  Would rolling back be appropriate in such a case?  It seems to violate the system of checks and balances for suggested edits.

*Non-Duplicates:*

- [Rollback an edit that skirts a SO rule?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252307/rollback-an-edit-that-skirts-a-so-rule) (The linked question is addressing edits that violate Stack Overflow rules, which this question is not.)
- [Rollback button in suggested edits queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251333/rollback-button-in-suggested-edits-queue) (The linked question is addressing adding a rollback button instead of it's proper use.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions

Comment: With that particular edit, I would have rolled back the mis-approved change and transferred the material that the OP added to the answer into the question as a 'this is how I am doing it'.  Somewhere along the line, I'd leave a comment that this shouldn't have been necessary.  The OP can edit his question; he shouldn't go tampering with answers like that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In general, if the code is correct (it corresponds to the text description in the answer) then leave it in the same answer. Why do you think a code-only answer or an answer with a duplicate text description or a question with the solution inlined would be better? The code that (OP only thinks) answers his question should also be posted as a (separate) answer even if incorrect, not in the question. If the code is not an answer (and OP knows it) then I agree -- its place is in the question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> It seems to violate the system of checks and balances for suggested edits.

Yes, but that system is already screwed. If you are thinking about whether or not to roll it back, your opinion is already better than two robo-reviewers.

If you find a blatantly terrible edit like that, certainly roll it back. If you aren't quite sure, don't do anything before getting a second and third opinion on chat or here on MSO.

Comment: Also, if you see a really terrible or vandalizing edit get approved, please flag the post to let us know about this. We can then look into it and ban reviewers as needed.

Comment: [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/4279): an incorrect (the code breaks in Python 2) edit was approved and (correctly) rollbacked.

Comment: My guess people got confused when they saw: **Edit (by OP)**, and thought that for some reason the OP was editing from another account.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest that you roll it back, but with a comment to the editor, who appears to be the original question asker, that he should edit his question or post his own answer.

Answer (score 8):

Go ahead & rollback questionable edits. The checks & balances clearly include the option for *someone else* to roll things back *AFTER* edits are approved. It’s not a statement of who is good, bad or otherwise but a statement that we are all human & the process of approving edits can be mechanical at best. So if you are not caught in that cycle, see something amiss, don’t feel like you are playing politics. Just do it.