# Suggested edit which got wrong approval

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

This question is very different from this: [Rolling Back Approved Edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253365/rolling-back-approved-edits)

This edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5043385 got approved while I was thinking to `Reject` it. The user who proposed this edit has commented like, "**formatted it**". When you look at the question, you can easily see that it's not just a "formation", but it's a "change in code along with formation". You can check its [**Revisions history link here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12313396/revisions)

Three reviewers "Approval" are required to get approved for this edit. I am wondering; how did each of the reviewers **make this approved.**

[image]

I still feel that, it's a "**wrong edit approved**", it should be "**rejected**" because it's not just formation, but also change (right/wrong that I don't know - because I am unaware of that language) in code.

If I am correct, what action could be taken, since its already approved?

**Feature request:**

---

Do we need a more button, "**Recheck**", to put it back in edit queue?

- A question with 3 "Recheck" mark will put back into edit queue.
- "Recheck" marked questions will have separate list, a user having "edit questions and answers" rights can check this list.
- Where they'll need to select either "**No Action Needed**" or "**Action Needed**" or "**Skip**"
- 3 actions will be needed for final review effect. What ever the action will get maximum count edit will be finalise. Actions could be either "**No Action Needed**" or "**Action Needed**".
- This entire flow is only acceptable, if owner of the question/answer wouldn't make any change.

Comment: Wait, where is the change in code you speak of? I don't see any.

Comment: Ah, I understand. You *think* the code was changed because markup was not rendered properly in the first revision (since the code was not formatted as code). It was there from the start, however, and the editor did not change it. Trying switching to "side-by-side markdown" mode and you should see it.

Comment: @Hemang press "side-by-side markdown" to see the source of the post. The code was not changed; the html tags were simply not displayed in an attempt to render them.

Comment: @Hemang: The code did **not** change. It really was **just a reformat**. Your premise is flawed.

Comment: @Hemang, did you try switching views, as we suggested? The markup portion of that code (`<a href='" + Url.Action("Index", "Home") + "'>`) was already present but not rendered in the first revision.

Comment: Check [this review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5040472), "thus" improved to "thusly" :-)

Comment: @Payeli While a valid point, this isn't about robo-reviewers. This is about the OP not reading the edit correctly. =)

Comment: @Hemang what do you mean it isn't show user updates?  There's no bug that I can see here.  The author posted html formatted as text.  By design the HTML is not rendered by Markdown.  Someone noticed this and edited the answer to format the html as code and now it shows up in the post itself.

Comment: oh, I missed that but now I understood. Thanks everyone! Can I edit my question to make it relevant only for feature request? How fair it would be? @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Can I edit my question to make it relevant only for feature request? How fair it would be?

Comment: @Hemang: I don't see any need for the request myself; this is only going to give robo reviewers another badge to pursue.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question(s):

> If I am correct, what action could be taken, since its already approved?

You could:

- leave a comment @[name of editor] and explaining your doubts about the edit
- leave a comment for the OP to check the edit
- rollback if you are sure the edit is wrong
- check with your peers in a chat room
- if it makes the  post useless, downvote it (although that is a bit harsh)
- in rare cases decide to ask a question on meta

Now for your feature request:

> Do we need a more button, "Recheck", to put it back in edit queue?

## NO

A suggested edit is already reviewed by at least 3 members or robo-reviewers. I don't think re-submitting a post over and over again in the queue is very productive or even annoying for the few reviewers that take the job seriously.

As stated above there are plenty of possibilities and features already available to improve quality on posts and redo or undo things that got screwed up.

I don't need another button.

Answer (score 1):

It was not actually a change in code, and the edit was 100% correct.

[Click "edit" on the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12313396/edit/6cd0790d-bec0-4069-bff1-6fff8a2748f0), and you will see that the OP **did** actually mean for it to have `<text></text>` and the `<a href` code in there.

Funnily enough, the resulting miss-formatted code with those hidden, looked almost like valid code. But the original poster actually submitted this exact (unformatted) code:

> columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='" +
>   Url.Action("Index", "Home") + "'>Create
>   Facility</a>").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: left;"
>   }).Width(60);
>
> This worked for me

Comment: The review queue shows both the rendered text and the markup diffs.  This particular reviewer just wasn't paying close enough attention.

Comment: Thanks, haven't looked at them in a while, and verified

Answer (score 1):

> (right/wrong that I don't know - because I am unaware of that language)

You skip the question. You don't have the domain knowledge to make a decision. You should not review a question where you don't know enough about what you're reviewing to make an intelligent decision.

And that's fine. No one is an expert in everything. Review the things you *do* know a lot about, or if you want to learn, do some research and enjoy the new knowledge.