# "Why not just delete the question?"

Tags: discussion, moderators

Yesterday, I asked a question, [Suggested edit which got wrong approval](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260317/suggested-edit-which-got-wrong-approval), by the time, I got many comments from the users though I found my self misunderstood the problem. However I feel that this question should get wide answer for my "Feature Request".. though I decided to pay moderator attention on this. I flagged my question with this,

[image]

My comments for the moderators,

> I missed something and asked a question wrongly. But this question still needs answer for "Feature request". Can I edit my question which only relevant for that "Feature Request"? How fair would it be?

After long stay on SO, I understood that once should not delete the question asked. I also read some where that, whatever the question/answer asked might help someone sometime (when) that we can't say.

- How I should take moderator comment?
- Should I delete my question?
- Or I should edit for that feature request?
- Or delete the question and asked a new question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators are not here for doing stuff you and/or the community can handle their self. They are more like exception handlers.

> How I should take moderator comment?

The moderator declined your flag because she/he did not feel what you asked for was an exception.

> Should I delete my question?

That is up to you. It has an upvoted answer now (which makes deleting no longer possible) but you can wait if other opinions arise. When reviewed by the team it might get a status tag on it.

> Or I should edit for that feature request?

You can always edit but now that it has an answer you can't change the post too much if that would alter its original intent.

> Or delete the question and asked a new question?

The problem with the question is that is not one but two questions. You see something bad happening and come to meta to clear that up. Based on either feedback or your own imagination you dream up a feature. You better stick to asking one question per post.

Comment: Note that he can't delete the question now, since the answer has received upvotes.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't upvote everything I post @Bart :)

Answer (score 2):

Rene's covered your questions but just a few examples of things I've successfully used mod flags for:

- changing duplicate target where the current duplicate was clearly incorrect.
- flagging a user whose posts weren't clearly spam, but when looked at together were in need of some mass deletion.
- flagging an answer that looks correct in the queue, but in context is a copy&paste of another answer.

Note that none of those were questions, they were all calls for action that only moderators could perform, and in all those flags I included every bit of relevant information (with links) the mod would need to act upon them.

Comment: was going to comment, but hit cap..