# Removing tag from question

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I just went through the list of suggested edits that I made and I observed a pattern: almost (if not all) questions that I removed the [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) tag had at least 2 rejects for `edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find...`. When I edited those questions I felt I was cleaning the [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) tag page, as none of those questions were related to the [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) pattern, however it seems that some people didn't agree with my actions.

So my question is: is removing a tag because that tag has nothing to do there, it doesn't add value to the question, and most likely the asker added it as his problem was related to a `MVC`-based framework/technology; is this a recommendable action? Or does it just pollute the moderators queue?

By the way, all the suggested edits mentioned about were approved, so I'm not complaining about something, just wanted to get the community's opinion on this subject.

Comment: I think you are correct, in that the [tag:model-view-controller] tag more than likely does not fit with the related asp.net mvc framework questions posted, and the removal of the tag in those cases seems to be the right action to take in my opinion.

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366942/can-we-warn-against-model-view-controller

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Did you just remove the tag or did you make other edits to the question as well?

I've just checked a couple of your suggestions and they were just to remove the tag. You did explain what you were doing in the edit comment, but people don't always read those.

I would guess that the rejects were from people who felt that you should have fixed other problems with the questions as well as removing the tag.

It might be better to hold off the "simple" retags until you reach 2k - and even then please review the whole question and see if there's anything else you can improve.

Comment: @Cristik: What ChrisF said. Fixing tags is a Good Thing, but if that's all you can do in an edit it's best you skip it and leave it for someone who doesn't need their edits approved by 3 other people. I guess you'll be able to do such edits yourself in a day or two, so this comment is mostly for the benefit of other sub-2k people.

Comment: Reviewers who don't read the edit comment should be banned forthwith!

Comment: @TRiG has a point. Some reviewers are plain annoying. There should be some sort of timeout for them like wrong flagging can get you some.

Comment: @Sufian: as far as I know you can get a ban from the review queue

Comment: I guess ban is automatically upon failing a few tests (of dummy/old reviews) like with flagging. I don't really think it is there with the reviews like the user is facing. There could well be a "claim incorrect review" where top moderators could discuss and check if claim's right and take action accordingly. It's complex but only this way reviewers could be kept on their toes.

Comment: @Sufian: you can flag for it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253365/rolling-back-approved-edits#comment13686_253370

Comment: @LisaMM thanks. It'd bookmark it but it wasn't what I was looking for. I was looking for a way to deal with suggested-edits/flags made/raised by me & were rejected. AFAIK there currently is no way than to post at meta, which is of course not very inviting as it demands writing/formatting, etc.