# What's the point of rejecting an approved suggested-edit that is likely to be approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rollbacks

I recently suggested an edit for an answer which was then [approved by two reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18620933).

The main reason of my suggestion is to improve the answer's formatting. Another reason (if there is) would be that I am trying to [keep the site clean and with good content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/7270869).

But the answer's owner doesn't seem to think the same with me (and the two reviewers). He then rejected and rolled back my suggestion, and finally let the answer in the badly formatted status.

**I am very curious about why did he reject the suggestion?** Was the answer supposed to look like that? I don't think so, because I would accept the answer content that is intentionally like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7270869), but that answer is simply not.

This is, on one hand, increasing my rejected edit count on my profile. On the other hand, it would definitely **discourage people to continue suggesting and improving the site content**.

---

I was looking on this meta, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253365/rolling-back-approved-edits) is the most related to this question, but that is about suggested edits which obviously shouldn't be approved.

Comment: *improved formatting* ... yeah, that clearly explains why you changed the first character of two words to a capital. And those two letters absolutely make the post much better and it is totally worth to have 2 reviewers spend their time on it ...

Comment: Only the OP knows *why* they rejected the edit, maybe it was a mistake or they had a reason. I'm not sure how you think meta can help here? Personally, I think this edit offers a small improvement, but this isn't very important.

Comment: @rene to be fair - it did fix the list formatting so that they're all at the same level rather than 2 and 4 being indented.. see the side-by-side view for revision #3...

Comment: If anything, the fix should have been complete: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15131/how-to-write-a-bulleted-list but I leave the nitpicking for others.

Comment: I think exactly as what @JonClements does.

Comment: @The-VinhVO rule of thumb is to make your edits as comprehensive as possible... you could have removed the "hope that helps" for instance and do a couple of other bits... Having said that, if I were you, I'd chalk it up to experience that these things happen, shrug it off and not worry about it.

Comment: I honestly think they use the indentation to indicate that they are on a sublevel in the UI, so not all actons need to be done from the same starting point. But I see the mod summoned the OP so they will probably give in and let it be.

Comment: Well, that sounds very reasonable @rene... and that proved that meta does help! :-)

As Jon and Rene have said, I would have improved much rather than just re-indent the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am very curious about why did he reject the suggestion

Why don't you ask them? You have comment privileges so you can leave a comment along the lines of

*I did suggest an edit because the indentation and capitalization in your answer looked off but I see you rejected it. For my own learning, would you mind sharing with me why I shouldn't have touched your answer?*

Beyond that we can all guess but as some, including a moderator, seem to agree that you were right, and the OP wrong, let me offer this option: They used the indentation to indicate that they are on a sublevel in the UI, so not all actions need to be done from the same starting point.

Your edit (and that of the moderator) ruined that distinction.

If anything, I suggest you be a bit more precise in your edit comment. *Improved formatting* can be a default text for almost all suggested edits, still the comment box is left empty so you could have typed: *I fixed the indentation so all numbers are on the same level, changed capitalization to be inline with the other list items*

I'm not a native speaker but it looks like lists have specific punctuation rules. If you want to be complete you could have applied [those](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15131/how-to-write-a-bulleted-list) but that might have required to edit the lead-in to that list as well.

When you suggest edits please try to be as complete as possible.

Comment: The indentation meaning that a menu sublevel does not read for me. That is, looking at the original post and the fact that `2.` is indented an extra step is in no way clear to me that the step is part of a sub menu. Especially when there's menu/submenu instructions indicated like this: *`Go to Settings > Technical > User Interface > Views`*. I mean, you could be right...but that distinction is both unclear and unnecessary.

Comment: To illustrate a Menu and submenu tree, _code formatting_ would be used instead of _the indentation_. About that more precise edit comment, I honestly expected that _Improved formatting_ was clear enough because OP might visibly recognize what I've done with the answer. +1 for your punctuation rules link, that absolutely helps a lot with my future posts. And you're right that I would have left a comment asking the reason for the rejecting. I will make better use of the comment area.