# Review queues: "I don't agree - could you please check that again"-Button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

When reviewing the outcomes of my decisions in the review queues, I sometimes see review results that, from my perspective, are clearly wrong. Especially in the Suggested Edits queue, sometimes very weird edits get accepted.

What is the right way to deal with that? Raising a moderator flag?

Wouldn't it be a nice feature to have some kind of <kbd>I don't agree</kbd> button when the review is finished?

Clicking this button could either send the particular item back to the queue for a second review, or let a moderator or higher reputation user to have a second look at it.

---

After receiving feedback I guess I can say that this proposition is controversial. **forsvarir** made a fair point in the comments:

> [...] clearly everybody that votes the opposite way to the final decision
>   disagreed with the outcome... That's why the system works based on the
>   majority of votes.

My point here is: sometimes the `majority of votes` decision does not reflect the opinion of the community - that's an issue arising from the fact that we select a very small number of reviewers. My idea to solve this is to make it somehow possible to increase the number of people judging a review, without increasing the review work to a level that cannot be handled anymore.

Having thought about that a second time, the proposal of a [meta-review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289026/meta-review-queue-but-who-will-review-the-reviewers-themselves) could be more general and better suited to solve this problem. Any suggestions and criticism are of course warmly welcomed.

Comment: I don't really see how this is any different to your existing vote in the queue.... clearly everybody that votes the opposite way to the final decision disagreed with the outcome...  That's why the system works based on the majority of votes.

Comment: @forsvarir I saw the OP's request as a desire to correct actions believed to be mistaken. (Which is reasonable since mistakes do happen, but I think they are less common outside of suggested edits.)

Comment: @forsvarir, that's true in some cases, but not all. Sometimes when I go through the previous edits I realize, that it was me who made a mistake.

Comment: @Radiodef, Yes `suggested edits`, is probably the most common queue for mistakes, but sometimes also `low quality` and `triage`. But in the triage queue the outcome is often debatable.

Comment: Just suggest an opposite edit? (The wikipedia way)

Comment: @Trilarion, I am over `2000` reputation, so I cannot really suggest anymore. If I make a change then it will automatically bypass the `review´ queues.

Comment: This whole question is "I know best. My vote should override other peoples' votes because I know best. Make that happen please."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, it may seem at first sight, but I can assure you that this is clearly not my intention here. I don't want to make my opinion decide, I want to make it possible to increase the number of people involved in a review, when I think it may have gone wrong.

Comment: @cel Well that is also a possibility. Just edit the question and improve it. You may not be able to undo the small rep for the suggested edit but you improve SO. Isn't that the goal?

Comment: I don't think this goes far enough. Each review should have a dedicated parent review. That way, the whole system will fall over, and there will be actual issues to discuss on meta.

Comment: @MichaelMroz, see my linked discussion about [meta-review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289026/meta-review-queue-but-who-will-review-the-reviewers-themselves?lq=1). Note however that judging from the votes, this idea does not  seem to be supported by the community

Answer (score 19):

If you have sufficient reputation (2000) you can revert the edit yourself or click 'Improve Edit' or 'Reject and Edit', both of which presumably remove the suggestion from the queue.

If a review mistake is particularly egregious, [you may flag the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253365/rolling-back-approved-edits#comment13686_253370) to notify a moderator (possibly with a link to the review).

Creating more reviews seems like a noisy solution to me. Also if we are talking about erroneous edits, creating a review is a slow path to correction. Better to correct it immediately yourself IMO.

If you are confident an action is an error, and have the privilege to overrule it, you may do so.

For other queues, I would have to say it depends on the situation. For example with low quality, you can flag the post again, but if the original flag was controversial you should put some extra thought in to it.

Reviewers/moderators do make mistakes occasionally but most of the time when a flag is disputed, it is because there simply isn't a majority opinion on whether it should be deleted or not. (See, for example, the *"doesn't answer the question/doesn't answer any question"* NAA debate.)

Especially when it comes to closing/flagging, I've only rarely seen an action that I disagreed with where, after researching the topic, it didn't became clear to me that my disagreement was misplaced or simply my opinion.

---

Other relevant discussion:

- [Rollback an edit that skirts a SO rule?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252307/rollback-an-edit-that-skirts-a-so-rule)
- [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back)
- [Spam-polishing audits (answer)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223141/spam-polishing-audits/223212#223212)

Although unrelated to queues, you might peruse something like [*is:question title:"why" [disputed-flags] or [declined-flags]*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20title%3a%22why%22%20[disputed-flags]%20or%20[declined-flags]) to see examples of flags that are controversial or ambiguous.

Comment: The problem with a rollback is that this is basically cheating the review system. It's like saying: Yes you all think this edit is okay, but I will reject and don't really care about what you were actually voting.

Comment: It *circumvents* the queue but a rollback is a non-queue option ([at this time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251333/rollback-button-in-suggested-edits-queue)). Rollback exists so incorrect edits can be rolled back so of course we may use it. See for example the discussion here: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253370/2891664](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253370/2891664). (Clicking 'Reject and Edit', then adding zero-width whitespace would certainly be *cheating* but I don't recommend that.)

Comment: @cel if you've noticed this and taken the time to look over the post itself, you've probably spent a lot more time than the people who just clicked 'approve'.  There's no need to feel bad about using your own judgement.